# Trouble with WaitForSeconds() in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am trying to invoke a shooting animation in the Update function and then wait for 0.5 seconds before spawning a laser shot. The below code isn't working for me. What can I do to achieve the desired result?

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Shoot"); // Start animation

        WaitAndShoot();         
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitAndShoot()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    Instantiate (shot, shotSpawn.transform.position,shotSpawn.transform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: I found this http://www.unitygeek.com/coroutines-in-unity3d/ very helpful to understand Coroutines in Unity3d

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're forgetting to call it as a coroutine using [`StartCoroutine()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

It should be:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Shoot"); // Start animation

        StartCoroutine(WaitAndShoot());         
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitAndShoot()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    Instantiate (shot, shotSpawn.transform.position,shotSpawn.transform.rotation);
}
```

Keep in mind that this still allows you to trigger multiple shots before the first shot has been spawned. If you want to prevent that from happening, keep track of a shot being fired or not with a boolean, and check for that in addition to your GetMouseButtonDown.